# JSFiddle toggle example not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement simple JSfiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/HjJBZ/

However when I load it to my site (not JSFiddle!) it is not working. I have checked the console and it seems to say :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of null(anonymous function) @ VM2075:1Xd @ g:108Ah @ g:176gh @ g:163(anonymous function) @ g:164(anonymous function) @ g:125(anonymous function) @ g:101(anonymous function) @ g:20(anonymous function) @ 1025104082-3?mr=t1433769737&mi='2.2082777797.1433755870147'&mt=!n&cs=!t

My HTML code is:

```
<style type="text/css">button#show2 {
  background-color: #323470;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 4%;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
  padding-left: 22%;
  padding-right: 22%;
}
#two {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 97%;
    height: 200px;
        background-color: #fff9d7;  
    border: 1px solid #e2c822;  
    color: #333333;  
    font-size: 13px;  
    font-weight: bold;  
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<button id="show2">Finance Available &gt;&gt;.</button>
<div id="two">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae augue libero. Nulla consequat leo malesuada condimentum rutrum. Vestibulum et mattis lacus. Nullam nec ex diam. Sed malesuada lorem quis tempus interdum. Nunc posuere ipsum vitae turpis luctus dapibus. Nam commodo efficitur justo, vitae gravida justo.</p>
</div>
```

My JavaScript code is:

```
 $('document').ready(function() {
    $('#show2').click(function() {
        $('#two').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: you should go over the [jQuery Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp). `$('document')` will search for literal `<document>` elements.

Comment: Remove "" in document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this by removing the quotes from `$('document')` else it will search for the `<document>` elements as you are using the [selector](https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) element.:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#show2').click(function() {
        $('#two').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HjJBZ/267/)**

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `$(document)` without quotes.

Currently you are using [`Element Selector ("element")`](https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/). Since we don't have `document` element your code doesn't works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#show2').click(function() {
        $('#two').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
button#show2 {
  background-color: #323470;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 4%;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
  padding-left: 22%;
  padding-right: 22%;
}
#two {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 97%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff9d7;
  border: 1px solid #e2c822;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="show2">Finance Available &gt;&gt;.</button>
<div id="two">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae augue libero. Nulla consequat leo malesuada condimentum rutrum. Vestibulum et mattis lacus. Nullam nec ex diam. Sed malesuada lorem quis tempus interdum. Nunc posuere ipsum vitae turpis
    luctus dapibus. Nam commodo efficitur justo, vitae gravida justo.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The $('document') selector is incorrect. Try $(document), I have tested the below and it works fine

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#show2").click(function(){
            $("#two").slideToggle();
        });
    });
```